# How to detect when screen is called even when its already focused? (react navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I know that I can listen to the change of the screen BUT what if I am calling AGAIN the same screen I am already focused on? I tried with the listener below and it doesnt detect:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.subscribeFocusHomeScreen = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     const logmeout = (this.props.route.params && this.props.route.params.data) ? this.props.route.params.data : '';
     if (logmeout == 'Logout') {
        this.popOutToastMsg();
        this.removeTimerFromNavHeader();
        this.cancelAllSubscriptions();
        this._logOutHandler();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
     }
  });
 ...
}
```

'focus' listener works when I go from screen B to A but not if I click on a button on sidebar which sends me to screen A (if I am already on screen A).

Comment: is it impractical to trigger the function from the button, instead of on navigation?

Comment: If the approach outlined in above comment does not work for you, take a look at [getId](https://desora.planio.com/issues/324) prop for the screen. Beware though that it adds a new screen to the stack with same component but different id.